# Reactjs - Hide address bar in mobile browsers (Chrome/Safari)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mobile

I am building a Web Shop with Reactjs. My goal ist to prevent vertical scrolling and only navigate with horizontal slider. Everything is working fine, here you can see the result: 
[image]

The height of all the components is changing dynamically according to the viewport height, for which I am listening for changes. 
To summarize: The page is always exactly 100% high.

**My Question is:**

How do I remove the address bar in mobile browser? I tried almost everything.

```
    window.scrollTo(0,1);
    window.scrollIntoView(behavior: "smooth");
```

did not work, even when I increased the height of my site to 110%. **I see the scrolling of my page, but the content is scrolling just under the address bar of the browser.** I used refs and ids to scroll specific components into the view, did not work neither...Wrapping the scrollTo function in a TimeOut has no effect. The address bar stays fixed on top of my page...
I also do not want to add the page to my homescreen and work with metatags in my manifest.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this is a tricky one I think. Meta tags (like `"display": "standalone",` etc.) in the manifest file and adding to home screen would be you best options I believe.

However, If you have made up your mind about this and need another solution my suggestion is to have a look at the fullscreen API. You should know that  iOS Safari doesn't have a fullscreen API though. So for apple's mobile devices I believe your only option is manifest/add to homescreen.

Google has provided some more information about this here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about the "standalone" approach, but to be honest, I don't think that anyone adds a webshop to his homescreen. I did never do it... Stumbled about that fullscreen API before and will give it another try :)

Comment: EDIT: I see that the Fullscreen Mode can only be initiated by a user gesture. Not exactly what I am looking for...

Comment: I know aliexpress has had some success on its pwa (standalone) compared to there app actually. Worth looking into. On androids there are actually a way you can add a “download as app” button to the webpage that adds it for you. I hope to see this functionality added to iOS devices as well soon. But that is up to apple ;)